# How can you render React.js components using Express.js?

Tags: reactjs, express

So I was wondering if I could render react components using Express.js. I have made the front-end of my webapp, but I can't find a way to render them using Express.js. If this sounds like total nonsense, here's and example of what, I've tried:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");

const app = express();


app.set('views','./Pages');



//Routes

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "Pages", "Home.js"))
})


//Start Server
app.listen(4000, () => {
  console.log("Server Has Started");
});
```

I have more mongoose code, but I deleted it in this example. So whenever I try to render it, it just renders the entire React file as plain text.

So I was wondering if there are any libraries or a way to render React components or React files in general in app.get() functions. Sorry if this makes very little sense. Or should I use express within the React.js file?

Comment: It's not 100% clear what you're asking. Are you asking about server-side rendering? If not--React components are rendered on the *client* side. React applications are a combination of HTML (often very minimal) and the application file containing the transpiled JS and supporting libraries. You might want to take a quick step back and search for "serve React app with ExpressJS" or something.

Comment: @DaveNewton Sorry for not being able to describe it more clearly, but basically, whenever you call `app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("Home");
})`, it would render out the html file, but I was wondering if there is a way to make Express render out React components. Because all I've found currently is that I need to use Axios to connect express with react. I have never linked react with express yet, so this is the first time and that is just my guess is that I could somehow render out React files with Express.

Comment: Please check out what SSR (Server Side Rendering) is. I don't think that's what you mean. It's not entirely clear what you actually want to do--I think you may not quite have a handle on how React works--React still requires an HTML page, because that's what clients (browsers) know how to render. It can be nearly *empty* HTML, but there still has to be something for React to render its components *in* to.

Comment: My recommendation is the same: take a step back and find a good tutorial specific to your needs and start there: there's a fair amount of "stuff" to digest to get all this working, and a tutorial and/or starter project will make it a lot easier.